# How jasmine defined its toEquals

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I looked up the jasmine source code, but didn't find the implementation for toEquals properly, What I found is below, in https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js line number 2331. But I need to know, where is the implementation for util.equals

```
  getJasmineRequireObj().toEqual = function() {

  function toEqual(util, customEqualityTesters) {
    customEqualityTesters = customEqualityTesters || [];

    return {
      compare: function(actual, expected) {
        var result = {
          pass: false
        };

        result.pass = util.equals(actual, expected, customEqualityTesters);

        return result;
      }
    };
  }

  return toEqual;
};
```

Can anyone help me to find the implementation for util.equals

Comment: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js#L1932

Answer (score 2):

The `util` object is defined in the [`matchersUtil`](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/bad9c63bf72fd32d6fb816185276036dc8aed6bd/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js) script. The "equals" function is based on the `eq()` function defined [here](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/bad9c63bf72fd32d6fb816185276036dc8aed6bd/src/core/matchers/matchersUtil.js#L81) - it is heavily based on / inspired by the `underscore`'s [`isEqual()`](http://underscorejs.org/#isEqual).